# pandas iterate over one column over unique value and get another column's values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this, and I'd like to iterate over the product column and get the second last and third last value from dates for each individual product(A and B)..

```
0. product Date  earning
1. A       202001 123 
2. A       202002 145
3. A       202003 150
4. A       201401 160
5. A       Total  578 
5. B       201901 123 
6. B       201902  145
7. B       201903  150
8. B       201402  160
9. B       Total   578
```

below is the sample code i'm trying

```
dates1 = []
dates2 = []


for i in (0,len(test2['product'])):
    s = re.findall('\d+',str(test2.loc[test2.index[-2],'Date']))
    dates1.append(s)
    e = re.findall('\d+',str(test2.loc[test2.index[-3],'Date']))
    dates2.append(e)
```

output required :

```
date1 = [201401,201402]
date2 = [202003,201903]
```

i.e. only two dates(from second last and third last line) for each individual product..

I'm actually bad with loops, so Can anyone help?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`df.groupby.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
In [683]: date1 = df.groupby('product').Date.nth(-2).tolist()

In [684]: date2 = df.groupby('product').Date.nth(-3).tolist()

In [685]: date1
Out[685]: ['201401', '201402']

In [686]: date2
Out[686]: ['202003', '201903']
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, without a loop, using `pd.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
date1 = list(test2.groupby("product")["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-2])
date2 = list(test2.groupby("product")["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-3])
```

**EDIT**

Or, as pointed out by @yatu, even better, you can also take advantage of `nth`:

```
date1 = list(test2.groupby("product")["Date"].nth(-2))
date2 = list(test2.groupby("product")["Date"].nth(-3))
```

Comment: You can use [`groupby.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) instead of using that custom lambda func

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
date1=[test2[test2['product']==i].iloc[-2]['Date'] for i in test2.product.unique()]
date2=[test2[test2['product']==i].iloc[-3]['Date'] for i in test2.product.unique()]

>>>print(date1) 

[201401,201402]

>>>print(date2

[202003,201903]
```

Comment: Chained indexing is is discouraged in the docs, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html